# Что означает символ собачки в коде vue.js @/components/HelloWorld.vue?

Tags: vue.js

В ново установленном коде vue.js путь к компоненту начинается с символа собачки `@/components/HelloWorld.vue`.

Что оно означает  можно ли изменить его на  символ `.`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это алиас ([alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias)) для удобного доступа к файлам. Ну чтобы не писать такое: `import Component from "../../../../components/component.vue"`

Обычно алиас `@` настраивают, чтобы он смотрел на корень каталога с исходниками.